# "cdk" command not found after installing python version

Tags: aws-cdk

The "cdk" command is not found after installing with "pip install --upgrade aws-cdk.core" (per the docs).

The package successfully installs because it is found in the "site-packages" directory.

```
tennis.smith at C02TM089GY6N in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
$ ls
README.txt                        cattr/                        docopt-0.6.2.dist-info/  pip/                              requests-2.22.0.dist-info/          typing_extensions.py
__pycache__/                      cattrs-0.9.0.dist-info/       docopt.py                pip-19.3.dist-info/               setuptools/                         urllib3/
attr/                             certifi/                      easy_install.py          pkg_resources/                    setuptools-41.2.0.dist-info/        urllib3-1.25.6.dist-info/
attrs-19.3.0.dist-info/           certifi-2019.9.11.dist-info/  idna/                    publication-0.0.3.dist-info/      six-1.12.0.dist-info/               wheel/
aws_cdk/                          chardet/                      idna-2.8.dist-info/      publication.py                    six.py                              wheel-0.33.6.dist-info/
aws_cdk.core-1.13.1.dist-info/    chardet-3.0.4.dist-info/      jsii/                    python_dateutil-2.8.0.dist-info/  tests/                              yarg/
aws_cdk.cx_api-1.13.1.dist-info/  dateutil/                     jsii-0.19.0.dist-info/   requests/                         typing_extensions-3.7.4.dist-info/  yarg-0.1.9.dist-info/
```

Any ideas why it isn't being detected?

Comment: What you are installing is the python library. If you want the command you have to install cdk cli as @isak pointed out in his solution

Comment: I would recommend you not install it globally but instead rely on "npx cdk" as a prefix for all CDK related commands. You get the latest version of CDK in that way. E.g. "npx cdk deploy".

Answer (score 3):

To install the CDK CLI run `npm install -g aws-cdk`.